# Produce background map images for plotting data with Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am submitting a manuscript for journals that do not accept background tile images from ArcGIS or similar services.

I thought it would be easy to produce your own images with GEE. I wrote this code combining examples I found on the web. I export this image and end up using QGIS to select bands, edit and produce a final pdf, svg or png.

However, I would like to:

1. export a thumbnail, pdf, png image that is ready to be used as background. Ideally an image that is no more than 20Mb, given any polygon.
2. spice-up the background image so it looks more similar to the tiles of any GIS service.

My ideal result is an image that looks pretty much like a screenshot of Google Earth (or maybe even one in black and white, greyscale, so that data plotted on top would visualize better, straight out of GEE and without having to use QGIS.

This is the code:

```
var geometry = 
    /* color: #d63000 */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-81.29700581101451, 14.41901072292579],
          [-81.29700581101451, -7.683476214952404],
          [-63.718880811014515, -7.683476214952404],
          [-63.718880811014515, 14.41901072292579]]], null, false);


// Function to cloud mask from the pixel_qa band of Landsat 8 SR data.
function maskL8sr(image) {
  // Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
  var cloudShadowBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(3).int();
  var cloudsBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(5).int();

  // Get the pixel QA band.
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));

  // Return the masked image, scaled to TOA reflectance, without the QA bands.
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)
      .select("B[0-9]*")
      .copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
}

// Map the function over one year of data.
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
    .filterDate('2016-04-01', '2018-7-31')
    .map(maskL8sr)

var composite = collection.median();

var VIS = {bands: ['B3', 'B5', 'B7'], min: 0, max: 0.747};

// Display the results.
Map.addLayer(composite,VIS ,"compt2");

//export image

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: composite,
  description: 'background-image',
  scale: 10000,
  region: geometry,
  maxPixels: 1000000000
});
```